# Store log output of many JBoss instances in a single location

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I have several machines on Amazon each running a JBoss 4.2.3. Although all JBoss instances serve a single web application they are unaware of each other because they are behind an ELB (Elastic Load Balancer). Now each instance has its own server.log file. Is it possible to store the log output of all instances in a single location? Can this be done through jboss-log4j.xml of JBoss? I would appreciate some recommendations on how such a solution can be implemented.

Regards

Comment: These is very similar question (JBoss uses log4j for logging): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596092/logging-from-multiple-apps-processes-to-a-single-log-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SyslogAppender in log4j to send the output of all instances to a central syslog daemon on one of your EC2 instances.