# Weblogic writes to rotated file

Tags: log4j, weblogic, cluster-computing

In our clustered project we have 2 machine, each machine has 3 instance of our web application based on Spring MVC 1.2.8, Log4J 1.2 and JDK 1.4 on Weblogic Server 8.1. Each machine has a log location. 3 instance writes to same file.

One of the system admin realized that after the log file is rotated the application writes to both rotated file and orginal file.

What can be wrong?

Here is our Log4J.xml configuration:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
#
# Set root logger levels and attach appenders
#
#----------------------------------------------------------

log4j.rootLogger=WARN

#----------------------------------------------------------
#
# Define and configure appenders
#
#----------------------------------------------------------

log4j.appender.MY_CONSOLE_1 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.MY_CONSOLE_1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MY_CONSOLE_1.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1 = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1.File = /logs/appdomain/application/application.log
log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1.MaxFileSize = 10000KB

log4j.appender.sendFile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.sendFile.File = /logs/appdomain/application/WS.log
log4j.appender.sendFile.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.sendFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sendFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n

# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MY_LOG_FILE_1.layout.ConversionPattern = %p %d %c - %m%n

#----------------------------------------------------------
#
# Attach appenders and set trace levels for each base
# package. Siblings will inherit appenders and trace level.
#
#----------------------------------------------------------

log4j.category.com = WARN, MY_CONSOLE_1
#------------------------------------------------------------
# to avoid duplicate logging
#------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.additivity.com=false
log4j.category.jsp = WARN, MY_CONSOLE_1
log4j.category.applicationException = WARN, MY_CONSOLE_1, MY_LOG_FILE_1



#----------------------------------------------------------
#
# Overide trace levels for individual sub-packages of
# interest.
#
#----------------------------------------------------------

log4j.category.com.application = WARN,  MY_LOG_FILE_1
log4j.category.WSLOG = INFO,sendFile
log4j.category.org.apache.axis = WARN,MY_LOG_FILE_1
```

Comment: Writing to a shared file is generally a bad idea. Check out [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596092/logging-from-multiple-apps-processes-to-a-single-log-file) for details.

Comment: The log file is not network shared. 3 instances is writing to the same file on the harddisk.